# Phonegap geolocation not working properly until device is restarted

Tags: geolocation, cordova

Trying out the geolocation of the phonegap. I noticed that it just keeps trying to get location if you don't put a timeout. Wifi and all configurations is fine. There was nothing wrong with the code so I tried to restart the device and it is now working.

What is causing this to happen and how do you prevent this bug?

Phonegap version and device: 2.5.0 and samsung s4 4.2.2

sample code in phonegap docs was used ([documentation code sample link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition)).

Thanks.